# php development in eclipse on ubuntu

Tags: php, eclipse, ubuntu

I have created a PHP project through eclipse. I put the project into `/var/www/` directory. I couldn't open the project through Eclipse. It says :

```
couldn't read the contents of the file. Permission denied.
```

Comment: check if you have read and write permission on the file. normally users won't have permission on `/var/www/`

Comment: how it check it? and how to have permission for that?

Comment: I think you can get better help at [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Check the permissions/owner of the project folder. You can do this:

1. Change the permission by `CHMOD`
2. Change the owner to the user of your system by `CHOWN`

Answer (score 0):

If you are in the development mode and the project is not public you can give all the permissions to all the users, so that your IDE can read and write your source codes:

```
chmod 777 -R /var/www/project_folder
```

or you can run eclipse as super user:

```
sudo ./eclipse
```